# Parsing XSI with Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to parse XML strings into a Document that I can use for easy searching. But when I run into certain kinds of XML, it doesn't seem to work. The document is never constructed, and is null when it encounters an XML message like I have at the bottom. An excpetion is not thrown by anything in my try/catch

My code currently looks like this:

```
Document convertMessageToDoc(String message){
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(message));

            doc = db.parse(is);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            doc = null;
        }

        return doc;
    }
```

What are some ways that I would be able to work with something like this:

```
 <ns1:SubmitFNOLResponse xmlns:ns1="http://website.com/">
 <ns1:FNOLReporting xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns1:FNOLReporting">
 <ns1:FNOLResponse>
 <ns1:FNOLStatusInfo>
  <ns1:StatusCode>0</ns1:StatusCode> 
  <ns1:StatusMessages /> 
  </ns1:FNOLStatusInfo>
  </ns1:FNOLResponse>
  </ns1:FNOLReporting>
  </ns1:SubmitFNOLResponse>
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?

Comment: Does it really not have an enclosing tag? Technically I'm not sure it'd valid as-is. There's no exception because when there is one, you don't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document is not well-formed XML. Once it is, everything appears to work as expected.

```
String message =
        "<ns1:Prods xmlns:ns1='/foo'>"// xmlns:ns1='uri'>"
                + "<ns1:Prod>"
                + "  <ns1:ProductID>316</ns1:ProductID>"
                + "        <ns1:Name>Blade</ns1:Name>"
                + "</ns1:Prod>"
                + "<ns1:Prod>"
                + "  <ns1:ProductID>317</ns1:ProductID>"
                + " <ns1:Name>LL Crankarm</ns1:Name>"
                + "  <ns1:Color>Black</ns1:Color>"
                + "</ns1:Prod>"
                + "</ns1:Prods>";

Document doc = null;

try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(message));
    doc = db.parse(is);

    NodeList sections = doc.getElementsByTagName("ns1:Prod");
    int numSections = sections.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < numSections; i++) {
        Element section = (Element) sections.item(i);
        NodeList prodinfos = section.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < prodinfos.getLength(); j++) {
            Node info = prodinfos.item(j);
            if (info.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                System.out.println(info.getNodeName() + ": " + info.getTextContent());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    doc = null;
}

// Outputs

ns1:ProductID: 316
ns1:Name: Blade

ns1:ProductID: 317
ns1:Name: LL Crankarm
ns1:Color: Black
```

Comment: I edited my example XML to something much closer to what I'm working with

Comment: @user906153 Well that was a waste of my time. Still works fine with your new XML; see my code for accessing elements and children. I'd sure recommend an easier approach, though, like dom4j/jaxb/etc. instead of doing everything manually--xpath makes everything easier.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your document is not "well formed". You need a single root element where you have two sibling "ns1:Prod" tags at the root.

Comment: I edited my example XML to something much closer to what I'm working with